# Are comments invoking code a language feature or antipattern?

Tags: php, comments

I stumbled upon some Nette code where comments were used to set class attribute, and the [Nette doc approves it](https://doc.nette.org/en/3.0/di-usage):

```
class Foo {
  /** @var someClass @inject */
  public $bar;
}
```

Having PHP Reflection at hand, should I use coments invoking code more as a standard language feature ("comments based coding"), or should I avoid it as an antipattern? Are there any authoritative resources advocating or denouncing such comments handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP did not support annotations until recently. [PHP 8 introduced attributes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php). It was released in end of November 2020. As of now attributes are not widely supported.

The pseudo-annotations from your example are the current best practice used by most major frameworks and libraries like Doctrine ORM. The latter even provides a [doctrine/annotations-library](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.10/index.html) which makes using these user land-annotations more convenient.

As for an authoritative source for whether this is a good practice, it is explicitly mentioned in the RFC for the language feature: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2#userland_use-casemigrating_doctrine_annotations_from_docblocks_to_attributes (the syntax in the RFC looks different than the actual attribute syntax as it was changed).